# How to add GET param to SOAP call with JAX-WS

Tags: java, soap, get, jax-ws

I know it is a bit strange, but I have this request:
How can I add a GET param to a SOAP call handled by JAX-WS Java client.

I don't know why this param was not included in the WSDL. Is there any way to control the HTTP request and add this GET param?

The implementation was made by wsimport, so I have a standard `javax.xml.ws.Service` object.

Comment: So you are the client. And you want to add a GET parameter to the SOAP service URL which is in essence a POST request. Did I understand you right?

Comment: Unfortunately you're right. I need to add a queryParam (GET) to the POST request of a SOAP call